# django.db.utils.DatabaseError: ORA-00904: invalid identifier

Tags: python, django-models, oracle11g, many-to-many

I'm running an application on django 1.11 and as an Oracle Database 11G XE database engine. I have 3 tables producto, catalogo and catalogo_producto. The catalogo_producto table is an intermediate table between producto and catalogo. When making the migration of the tables, no problem arises, but when wanting to create an object the following error arises `django.db.utils.DatabaseError: ORA-00904: "CATALOGO_PRODUCTO". "ID": invalid identifier.`

I know that this error refers to the fact that I have not assigned any primary key in the model, but following the django documentation [Extra fields on many-to-many relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany) for these cases a primary key is not assigned to a specific field. I also understand that django in these cases creates a PK "ID" that is not shown in the models. So I do not know if the correct solution is simply to create an id field in the catalogo_producto table or is there some other solution?

models.py

```
class Producto(models.Model):
    codigo = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    precio = models.IntegerField()
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tipo = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    cantidad = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'producto'

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.codigo)

class Catalogo(models.Model):
    codigo = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    fecha = models.DateField()
    productos = models.ManyToManyField(Producto, through='CatalogoProducto')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'catalogo'

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.codigo)

class CatalogoProducto(models.Model):
    catalogo_codigo = models.ForeignKey(Catalogo, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='catalogo_codigo')
    producto_codigo = models.ForeignKey(Producto, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='producto_codigo')
    posicion = models.IntegerField()
    precio = models.IntegerField()
    imagen_producto = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/", default='')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'catalogo_producto'
        unique_together = (('catalogo_codigo', 'producto_codigo'),)
```

DDL Oracle

```
CREATE TABLE producto (
codigo     NUMBER(6) NOT NULL,
precio     NUMBER(8) NOT NULL,
nombre     VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
tipo       VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
cantidad   NUMBER(6) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE producto ADD CONSTRAINT producto_pk PRIMARY KEY ( codigo );

CREATE TABLE catalogo (
codigo        NUMBER(6) NOT NULL,
descripcion   VARCHAR2(250) NOT NULL,
fecha         DATE NOT NULL);

ALTER TABLE catalogo ADD CONSTRAINT catalogo_pk PRIMARY KEY ( codigo );

CREATE TABLE catalogo_producto (
catalogo_id       NUMBER(6) NOT NULL,
producto_id       NUMBER(6) NOT NULL,
posicion          NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
precio            NUMBER(8) NOT NULL,
imagen_producto   VARCHAR2(250) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE catalogo_producto ADD CONSTRAINT catálogo_producto_pk PRIMARY KEY(catalogo_id, producto_id);

ALTER TABLE catalogo_producto
ADD CONSTRAINT cat_prod_catalogo_fk FOREIGN KEY ( catalogo_id )
    REFERENCES catalogo ( codigo );

ALTER TABLE catalogo_producto
ADD CONSTRAINT cat_prod_producto_fk FOREIGN KEY ( producto_id )
REFERENCES producto ( codigo );
```

Comment: How are you trying to create the record in CatalogoProducto? When you are using a through Model, you have to create manually the object...

Comment: First I create a producto then a catalogo and when I try to create the record in CatalogoProducto the error arises. Everything I'm doing through the administrator.

Comment: Could you provide the table description of the table `catalogo_producto` in Oracle (list of all columns and constraints). The primary key column should be automatically created by Django with the name "ID". You are allowed to override this but it is not necessary. Did this table exist before? Have you run makemigrations/migrate without errors?

Comment: @Risadinha When I do the migrations, no error occurs. Only when I try to add a record in CatalogoProducto from the administrator.  I already shared the oracle DDL

Answer (score 0):

I found this issue on django project, which could be the answer:

> There's no bug here. By default, Django wants the column names of the join table between models Foo and Bar to be foo_id and bar_id. The columns of your intermediate table aren't called that, so the error is being raised when trying to execute the SQL on the intermediate (join) table.
>   To solve this, construct the intermediate table manually, specifying the names of the db columns and use the new through parameter on ManyToManyField to specify the intermediate model.

So, I think you have to change the column names in the intermediate model:

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/8339

Comment: The problem is when I first create the database from oracle through a script and then execute the migrations from django. What I did to solve was to get the models with python manage.py inspectdb> models.py and then make the migrations with that already working for me. I suppose that some error happened when having already some tables defined by the script.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the primary keys and foreign keys manually, it seems.

```
ALTER TABLE producto ADD CONSTRAINT producto_pk PRIMARY KEY ( codigo );
ALTER TABLE catalogo ADD CONSTRAINT catalogo_pk PRIMARY KEY ( codigo );
ALTER TABLE catalogo_producto
ADD CONSTRAINT cat_prod_catalogo_fk FOREIGN KEY ( catalogo_id )
    REFERENCES catalogo ( codigo );

ALTER TABLE catalogo_producto
ADD CONSTRAINT cat_prod_producto_fk FOREIGN KEY ( producto_id )
REFERENCES producto ( codigo );
```

You are pointing the foreign keys to non-existing primary keys. Does this even get created by Oracle? (Or maybe I am misreading this.)

Maybe you are creating these in your own SQL scripts or they have already been created.

Conventionally, in Django, you do not write the SQL scripts for creating the tables yourself but you write the models and then run:

```
./manage.py makemigrations # creates the files that create the DB structure
./manage.py migrate. # actually accesses the DB and creates the tables
```

Django will create the primary key columns, naming them `ID`. You need these columns for joins in general (you won't be able to join in Oracle with your current constraints, it should give you a very similar error to what you get from Django).

Django would also set the ForeignKey constraints up via `makemigrations` and `migrate`, naming them appropriately by using the field names in your models.

If you are allowed to create your own tables, remove all the `db_*` parameters from your code and run `makemigrations` because you won't have to bother checking for duplicate table names. Let Django do the work whereever you can.

Django migrations will help you keep track of changes that you make to your models over time and that need to be reflected in your DB structure. One of the reasons of using Django is exactly because you don't want to maintain that manually. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/migrations/.

Comment: Previously I had those columns with the name of catalogo and producto but I modified them following the response of this ticket https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/8339 Also for this case I generate the models with python manage.py inspectdb> models.py

Comment: Do you really need to name the DB tables and columns yourself? Can't you just make use of Django conventions? You will have a lot of additional work if your application grows. (Once you have 50+ models with hundreds of fields and cross relations you really don't want to micro-manage this by yourself, anymore, if noone pushes you to.)

Comment: The problem is when I first create the database from oracle through a script and then execute the migrations from django. What I did to solve was to get the models with python manage.py inspectdb> models.py and then make the migrations with that already working for me. I suppose that some error happened when having already some tables defined by the script. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @alejandrodxf - if you are the one who is defining the tables (and you are not required to use existing tables that are shared with other non-Django applications), then: dropdb <yourdb>, createdb <yourdb>, drop all the exisiting migration files in your apps, do `makemigrations` and then `migrate`. do NOT create any tables by yourself.

Comment: i have to agree with @Risadinha... If you are planning to use django for a long time app, the better idea is to rely the database structure to migrations.

Answer (score 0):

It looks you are creating DDL by hand or something else, because, if you digg into migration files, you will see that django wants to create `id` field:

```
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='CatalogoProducto',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True,                 #<---- here!!!
                                    primary_key=True, serialize=False, 
                                    verbose_name='ID')),
            ('posicion', models.IntegerField()),
            ('precio', models.IntegerField()),
            ('catalogo_codigo', models.ForeignKey(db_c...
```

Check for twice you are creating tables from migrations:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate   #<-------- this one creates the tables.
```

Comment: Yes, the problem was that it created the tables first from a script in oracle and then executed the migrations.

Comment: Pues la gracia de las migraciones está en no tener que escribir el DDL, ya sabes, DRY (don't repeat yourself)